# Setting up second website store symlinks

Tags: magento2

I have my magento build on a subdomain with the A record pointed to the host server.

I have set up the second website, the secondary domain, the `store/catalog`, edited and transfered the `index.php` and `.htaccess` files, and created the `symlinks`.

Here's where i think i went wrong. When i created the `symlinks`, i (stupid) wrote out the code provided, stupidly forgetting to replace example.com with the correct file path to the new domain. I tried to rm the links. It failed.

I don't understand this process. I was following instructions -blindly. Is there a place in the code base where this is hard coded and I can fix it? When i entered the ln -s commands, i was in the root of the domain.

I issued `ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/app/` app 
It seemed to have created the links.

I don't know how. And it failed to remove them with rm.